# org.apache.http.wire DEBUG logs cannot be muted

Tags: java, apache, http, log4j

I am using Apache HTTP library, which unfortunately logs action which significantly **slow down the program** (takes few seconds instead of miliseconds):

```
09:53:26.271 [Thread-18] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Y[0xc6][0x3]y[0xbf][0x1b][0xf1]e8[0x9d]?[0xc8]][0x83][0xc1]l[0xc5][0x96][0xbf]:[0x98][0xc1][0xf9][0xad][0xd7][0xb6][0xda]',[0xbd]S)[0xe2][0x12][0xd0][0x84]=[0x16][0x10]@[0x90][0x92][0xe7][0xb9]7S[0x8a][0x1]r[0xcb]V[0xc1]z[0xb9][0xed]-[0xe0]Xk +i[0xc9][0x3]4[0x1][0x16]5)j[0xeb][0xb8]][0x16]&[0x8][0xd9]to[\n]"
09:53:26.271 [Thread-18] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "2k[0xda][0x85][0xdd]-o[0x9f][0xdf][0xe6][0x10][0xa8]w[0x1b]Q[0xb3]\[0x16]u[0x2][0xd5]L[0xb5][0xff]|[0x14];@zV([0xef][\r]l[0xe2][0xb8][0x15][0xfd][0xf9]8"NX[0x1d][0xe7][0xff][0x97][0xba]N[0xba])[0xe7]Q[0xef]Q[0x98][0xcd][0x1a][0xef]1[0xf6][0xbb]w[0xd3][0xa7][0x8b][0x97][0xde][0x6][0xa7][0x96]PPu[0xa7][0x19][0xbe][0xbb][0xdf][0x14]D[\r][0xe3][0xd5][0x92]|[0xeb][0xec][0xd3]qFE%[0x98]Iv1[0xac]J([0x94][0x9b][0x10][0x87]c[0x9f][0x89][0xd5]-[0x8f][0x1][0xe5][0xe0]\n[0xd6]+S[0xd7][0x1c]V?[0x9c][0x9e]_=X?[0x6][0xd3]w[0x9f][0x96][0xcc][0x9e][0xbc][0xf3][0xc3][0xaa][0xd4]STO[0xfb]f[0x9e]@[0xce][0xfb][0x8e][0xde][0xd8][0xe]ChA[0x3][0x7][0x86][0xb5][0x86][0x2] VD[0x94][0x9b][0xe1][0xa9]c[0x82][0x15]LOn[0x95]{[0x1f]z[0x8]P[0xaa][0x98][0x98]:[0xea][0x97][0xe3][0xa4][0xa7][0x8a][0x88][0x8a][0x9]c[0x8c]/?<[0xcc][0xdf]j[0xd1][0xbd][0x15][0xfe]h[0x15][0xfe][0x8a][0xe5]d[0x8a])[0xd8][0xef][0x9f][0xcf][0x93][0xd8]e[0xa6]t[0xdd][0xbf][0xa6][0xa8][0x13][0xae][0xd9][0xfa][0x16][0xcb]]&[0xf0][0xd5]IZ[0xd7][0xdd]2N[0xc7][0xa2][0x85]b=[0x91][0xa9]cc[0x9f][0xf0][0xa6][0xaa][0xcb]eVS[0xc3]7p[0x9e][0x8d]\g[0xee]][0x98][0xa2]yyB7[0x82][0x12][0x96][0xae]o[0xf9][0xfa]}[0xb6][0x4][0xee][0x97][0xf0][0xe3][0x8f][0x15][0xec][0x83][0x97][0x7][0x1f][0xc1]oO[0xd3][0xdb][0xb][0x9][0xd7][0xf7]w[0x19]@,[0x84][0x84]$[0x9c]g[0xbb][0xd8]y[0xde][0x15][0x82][0xa5][0xb1]7[0x9e][0xca]rezPr[0x9f]X[0x9c]- [0xc1]9[0x82][0x13][0x80][0xd6]d[0x7][0xe3][0x12][0xd5]s[0x6][0xb6][0x15]d[0xbc]X[0xb1][0x86][0xfc][0xc]/[0x1d]i[0x18][0x90][0x18]VM[0x9c]N[0xf3][0x9c]m[0xe][0xb6][0x9e][0x93][0xbe]^4r[0xac]>vF[0x90]][0x9d][0xe2]l)[0x7][0x9c]F8#2[0xc1][0xb6]E[0xcc][0xcd]Hu[0x1a].4[0x83]=[0xd8][0xf9][0xf1]8'[0xbb][0xca][0xc1][0x9a]t[0x9f][0xce]u[0xc1][0x8c][0xec][0xce]a[0xa3]Z[0xbb][0xde]nFu[0xb][0xfe][0xdd]gA[0x5][0xaf][0x9c]z[0x9d]3[0xb1][0x81]j[0x9c][0x6][0xfc][0xe1][0xf1][0xa6][0xf1]4[0xf7][0xae][0xb][0xe7][0xa8][0xc1][0xf2][0xf9][0x9]z[0xa1]4[0x9f]uw[0xb2][0xa9][0x12]>[0xb3][0xb6][0x9e][0xbc]n[0x17][0x8e][0xf][0x88][0x81]g[0xcb][0x8e]r[0x9c]E$[0xea][0xff][ [0xe1][0x14][0xb0][[0xf0][0x8f][0xa1][0xcf][0xfb][0x93][0xf0][0x10][0x86][0xde]vx[0xd4][0xc1][0xcf]jP[0x80][0x91]j[0xcb]/f[0xd0][0xb9][0x84]6[0xe4]$[0xa0][0xc][0xc3][0xa8]gPHN[0xfc]u[0x8c]y[0x12][0x14][0xe4]AS[0xec]r[0xee][0xf3][0x88]E[0x1c]4[0xac][0xa7]1[0x87][0xe7][0xb]n[0x9c].[0xcb][0x2][0xfb][0xe6][0x1f][0xbe][0xa1]M[0xb9]W[0x11][0x8b] [0xf8][0x9b]Lv[0xa5]?[0xed]T[0x90][0xca][0x1a]5|[0xb5]YA[0xc7][0x12][0x91]%^[[0xbc][0xee][0xaa][0xe6][0x86][0x8c]Y[0xcd][0xd7][0x93]j[0xb][0xd6]LF/zN+[0xf4][0xfa][0x6]iJj[0xf6][0x1c][0xcf]k[0x8f][0x99][0x8a][0xba][0xc6][0xde][0x89][0x2][0xf1] +[0xf8][0xf2][0xac]B[0x82][0xa2][0xe3][0xcd][0xca][0xce][0xd7]{[0x8a][0x88][0xc7][0x80][0xc3][0xd5][0xaa];[0xf6][0x2][0xf8][0xc8]7[0x14][0x3][0x8a][\r]4[0xb1][0xc5][0xfe]n[0xcb][0x93]I[0x98]U.U8[0x9b][0x82]x[0x94][0x1c]f[0xe6][0x12][0x9b]f][0xe]c[0xa4][0xc8][0x83][0xc]|[0xa3]U[0xc9][0x11][0x83]v[0x1]RJ[0xaa])N[0xf5][0xcf][0xc8][0x7][0x88]Y[0x95][0xe7][0xa1]&[0xd4][0x8b]=+a[0xa8]i[0xca][0x85]6[0x82][0x12][0x84]d[0xf6]`[0xda]K[0xe6]z[0xfd]m[0xd8][0x2]Z[0xd6]w[0x7][0xa9][0x87]Q[0x5][0xf][0xc4][0x0][0xf9]T09[0x9f][0xab]z[0xf6][0x89][0x16][0xe5][0xd2][0xf6][0xd7][0x1f][0xd3][0x89][0xa3]s[0xc0][0xe5]F[0x12][0xdd][0xe3]e[0xf8][0x5]ft[0xd7][0x8][0xfd][0x9b][0xed][0xaf][0x83][0xc4][0xd3]W[0x9e][0xc6]Hl[0xdb][0xd4][0x12][0xf3]w|[0x98]EqS[0xeb]a[0xa1][0xab][0x1f][0xe]ea[0xc2]d[0xdd]xz[0xc6][0xb7][0xa7]O[0xdf]i[0xd5][0xea][0xe5]"[0xe0]t[0x1d]2[0xe2][0x17][\n]"
09:53:26.271 [Thread-18] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "t[0xc0]g[0xf4][0xf6][0x12][0xf1][0xcc]3[0x1b]D$jU\[0xab]e[0xc5][0xe7]=>[0x85][0xea][0xde]6[0x4][0xa9][0xf9]R[0xcc]$[0xc4][0x9][0x19]W[0xee][0xc5][0xb2][0xa4][0xe3][0xb4][0x92][0x1e]R[0x1][0xd2]Z^[0x95][0xa7][0xb0][0x9b][0x8][0xbe][0x1c][0xb5][0xcc]30[0xf]T[0xca][0x0][0xe7][0xef][0xf1][0xb6][0x99][0x96][0x94]q7[0xaa]3[0xce][0xa8][0x12]@[0x86][0x5]+Z[0x18][0x92][0xd2][0x84][0xf3]2[0xcc]8Y[0xcc][0xe4][0xa0][0x13]][0x1e][0xfa]d[0xd2][0xf5][0xa6]}[0xe3][0x5]I[0xd3]?W[0xb7][0xef][0x96][0xa0][0xf1][0xc3]W[0x8e]B[0xcf][0xc][0x1e][0xfc][0xe2];P[0x16][0x94][0xef][0xb2][0xee][0xd5][0xcb]|E[0x93][0xb2][0xcd][0xea]"hi[0x1c]`[0xea][0xe5][0x95][0xaf][0xea][0x9b]"[0xe][0x11]-oY[0xc6]D[0xf4][0xe]/#[0xdb]P[0xe4][0xa8][0xa7]0z[0x98]G7[\n]"
```

To my log4j.properties I put thses lines:

## log4j.properties

```
log4j.category.httpclient.wire.header=WARN
log4j.category.httpclient.wire.content=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=WARN
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=WARN
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=WARN
log4j.category.httpclient.wire.header=WARN
log4j.category.httpclient.wire.content=WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.http=WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.http.headers=WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.http.wire=WARN
```

I even put these lines to my code:

## JAVA code

```
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
```

The **problem** is, the **logging still persists**. It seems that log4j.properties has impact on other parts of JAVA code, but it is impossible to get rid of *org.apache.http* DEBUG logs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem with

`((Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire")).setLevel(Level.WARN);`